# Git branch diverged after removing a file that has moved

Tags: git, rebase

A file in the master repository had been moved into a subfolder, on my local server I deleted the file and was going to add it in on a future check in to the new location.

Upon checking in the commit and doing a `git pull --rebase origin master` I had a conflict stating that the file had been deleted in my commit and renamed/moved in a different commit so the merge failed.

I then did a `git rebase --abort`.

Now when I do git status I get the message:

> Your branch and origin/master have diverged and have 1 and 27 commits each.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the `git rebase` operation again from the start.

When you hit the step where there's a conflict (you deleted, other moved),
you need to decide how to resolve the conflict, preferably after discussing with the other developer who did the moving.

If the file should be removed, then delete it:

```
git rm path/to/renamed/file
```

If the file should remain, then add it:

```
git add path/to/renamed/file
```

The `path/to/renamed/file` is the conflicted path given by `git status`.

After you removed or added, continue the rebase with:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Note that if you decided to `git add` the conflicted file,
then when you do `git rebase --continue`,
it will probably tell you this:

> ```
> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
> If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
> already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.
> ```

Indeed, the file was already added by the other branch,
with your `git add` you just confirmed to keep that action,
without really adding anything new.
In this situation continue the rebase with `git rebase --skip`.

Comment: I have done git add the file in the new location, git status shows everything in green but doesn't include that new file in the list, does this mean that file is included and the old file will be removed?

Comment: The old file was removed in both branches, so that stays removed. If you do `git add`, the new file (the file at the new location) will be added. Btw, when you do `git rebase --continue` it will probably tell you "nothing to do", as indeed, the file was already added by the added commit, you are just confirming that when resolving the conflict, but there is no real change to do. In that case do `git rebase --skip`

Answer (score 1):

In the very beginning, the commit graph might be like:
[image]

You committed the change and it was like:
[image]

Then you wanted to do a rebase pull. First, `origin/master` was updated:
[image]

If the rebase pull was successful, the graph was expected to be like:[image]

However it failed due to conflict and you aborted it, so it became this again:
[image]

`master` and `origin/master` are diverged after `C`. If you want to avoid the conflict now, you could run `git reset HEAD^ --hard`, which makes the graph like:
[image]

And then update `master` with `origin/master` via `git merge @{u}` or `git merge origin/master`.
[image]

Now you can delete the file and commit the changes as you did at first. And the final graph will be like:
[image]

You can just ignore `D`, which now disappears from `master`'s git log though it will exist in the repo for quite a while.